# VueJS cannot render a dynamically generated component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, parceljs

I'm struggling to make this work. I'm developing a VueJS small app, served using ParcelJS.
In a view called `DisplayProgram`, I'm trying to create multiple instances of a specific component `ModuleListView`, with network fetched data.
When I try to display the components, I get this error : `[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.`

Here are the two views I'm using :

`DisplayProgram.vue`

```
<template lang="pug">
  div.grix.xs4
    div.col-xs4.row-xs5.row-md8.vself-stretch.vcenter
      transition(:name="getSlideSide()" mode="out-in")
        component(:is="getModuleListView()")
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import ModuleListView from './ModuleListView.vue';

@Component({
    components: {
      'module-list': ModuleListView
    }
})
export default class DisplayProgram extends Vue {
    @Prop() program: any;
    activeModuleList!: {name: string, number: number,  modules: Array<any>};
    activeModuleListNumber: number = 0;
    previousModuleListNumber: number = 0;
    moduleLists : Array<{name: string, number: number, modules: Array<any>}> = [];
    listViews: Array<ModuleListView> = [];
    async created() {
        this.moduleLists = this.getModuleLists(this.program);
        this.activeModuleList = this.moduleLists[0];
        this.emitModuleListChanged(this.activeModuleList.number);
        this.instanciateListViews();
    }

    instanciateListViews() {
      this.moduleLists.forEach(moduleList => {
          let moduleListView: ModuleListView = new ModuleListView(moduleList);
          Vue.set(this.$options.components, moduleList.number, moduleListView);
          this.listViews.push(moduleListView);
      });
    }

    getModuleListView() {
      return this.listViews[this.activeModuleListNumber];
    }

    getSlideSide() {
      if (this.previousModuleListNumber > this.activeModuleListNumber) {
        return "slide-right";
      }
      return "slide-left";
    }

    getProgramProgress() : {actualNumber: number, totalNumber: number} {
    return {actualNumber: this.activeModuleListNumber + 1 , totalNumber: this.moduleLists.length};
   }

    getModuleLists(program: any) : Array<{name: string, number: number,  modules: Array<any>}> {
        // Getting data and generating the javascript objects
        return moduleLists;
    }
    
    displayModuleList(index: number) {
      this.emitModuleListChanged(index);
    }


   emitModuleListChanged(moduleListNumber: number) {
     this.previousModuleListNumber = this.activeModuleList.number;
     this.activeModuleList = this.moduleLists[moduleListNumber];
     this.$emit("module-list-changed", {moduleList : this.activeModuleList, total : this.moduleLists.length});
     this.activeModuleListNumber = moduleListNumber;
   }
    
}
</script>


<style scoped>
</style>
```

`ModuleListView.vue`

```
<template lang="pug">
  div
    h2.txt-center.responsive {{moduleList.name}}
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
    components: {
    }
})
export default class ModuleListView extends Vue {

    @Prop() moduleList!: {name: string, number: number,  modules: Array<any>};

    constructor(moduleList: any) {
      super();
      this.moduleList = moduleList;
    }

    async created() {
      console.log("modulelistview is created");
    } 

}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
.responsive {
  font-size:3vw;
}
</style>
```

Do you have a solution for this, folks ? Thank you for your help !

Comment: Apparently the compiled 'pug' template is not being passed in as the template attribute of vue component,  idk why.

Comment: I also think it has to do with the way Parcel compiles everything. But I can't tell what's going wrong.

Comment: Is there an official documentation/guide that says pug will properly handle vue.js shorthand bindings and such?

Comment: I'm using Pug for the whole project, and it correctly handles the bindings. This is the first time (Component instanciation in code) this error occurs.